# Best way to convert FAQ with images into a knowledge base for a QnA bot

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I have an FAQ document (MS word) that I want to convert into a QnA knowledge base to support a QnA bot.  I can use QnA Maker to import text from the document but all images get stripped out.  Without the images the answers are nonsensical.  I know QnA maker supports markdown so I could add the images back with image markdown tags.  This is time consuming and requires the images be stored somewhere that can be accessed by QnA maker (eg Azure blog storage).  The other issue with this is that my bot uses Hero Cards for follow on questions (I believe this is the recommended approach for handling follow on questions).  However, Hero Cards don't support markdown.  I could use adaptive cards instead of hero cards.  Adaptive cards do support markdown but not the image tag :(.  Also, markdown is not exactly user friendly.  It's fine if someone technical is managing the KB.  But if this is the responsibility of a non-technical person then markdown isn't ideal.

The fact that QnA Maker doesn't effectively support images seems like a significant oversight.  I get that bot conversations should involve short exchanges between bot and user.  But (apologies for the cliche) a picture is worth a 1000 words sometimes.

Griping aside, does anyone have suggestions on how to effectively build a KB with images?  I'm also open to alternative suggestions on how to use a bot as a front end to an image rich FAQ.  I should also add that my bot is accessed via MS Teams.

Thanks

Comment: I'd highly suggest asking this question the MS Azure support directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer but I just noticed (or QnA interface was recently added) that you can edit QnA answers without the need to write markdown directly (hurray!).  You can even add images though you still need to store/organize them yourself
 [(screen shot of edit bar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36yiu.png).  You can also leave your answer as MD if you'd prefer to edit them directly.